# Biblatex: tricks with repeated citations in footnotes

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm trying to adapt the citation formatting provided by the `verbose-trad2` style for **biblatex** to conform to very particular specifications I've been given. I *think* `verbose-trad2` is the closest to all my needs amongst the default ones.

The citations are to be given in footnotes, usually as `\footcite{}`, but occasionally with `\footnote{Some remark... \cite{}.}`.
What I call here a *full citation* is the whole info on a work: author, title, publisher, date, etc. What I call an *abbreviated citation* is just author (always complete!), abbreviated title, and optionally the page number. The first time a work is cited, I must use the full citation, and then it depends on whether other works are cited in between or not, but never more than the abbreviated citation.

The biblatex related code I've already come up with can be found [here](http://www.silentdrift.net/biblatex/biblatexCB_SX.tex). The LaTeX document itself is an `article` with the option `onepage`.

First, two hacks I have already applied.

1. Always print the full name of the author. Thus I set `idemtracker=false`.
2. The word *Idem* must be used when two subsequent citations share the same author and title (instead of the default *Ibid* in `verbose-trad2`). Thus I redefined `ibidem = idem`.

Second, there are things I still need to adapt, for which I don't have the faintest idea, even after looking through the documentation and this site. (I may have missed something, because I'm not at ease with low-level tex or biblatex code, I apologize if that's the case.)

1. When two subsequent citations share the same author, title and page number (given in the square bracket argument of the `\footcite[]{}` command), just print *Ibid.* (nothing else).
2. Always begin the foonote section of a new page with a full or abbreviated citation (author (full), abbreviated title, page number), never start with an *idem* or *ibid.* even if the last citation on the previous one is similar/same. I thought the biblatex documentation implied this would work out of the box, but it doesn't seem to.
3. (Optional) Abbreviated title means: if there is only one work by the author, use the expression *op. cit.*, else use an abbreviated form of the title (do I necessarily have to use the `shorttitle` field in the bibTeX entries?)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help!

Comment: Just for completeness's sake, I found this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20895/difference-between-footcite-and-cite-in-biblatex) that might help one day, seeing the way I mix `\footcite` and `\footnote{ ... \cite ... }`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For request no. 1, add the option `ibidpage=true`. Quoting p. 2 of `75-style-verbose-trad2.pdf`:

> The `ibidpage` option
>
> The scholarly abbreviation *ibidem* is sometimes taken to mean both
>   ‘same author + same title’ and ‘same author + same title + same page’
>   in traditional citation schemes. By default, this is not the case with
>   this style because it may lead to ambiguous citations. If you you
>   prefer the wider interpretation of *ibidem*, set the package option
>   `ibidpage=true` or simply `ibidpage` in the preamble. The default
>   setting is `ibidpage=false`.

For request no. 2, an `\iffirstonpage` test has to be added to the `cite` bibmacro; if the test yields true, the bibmacros `cite:name` and `cite:title` have to be used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,ibidpage=true]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \bibhypertarget{cite\the\value{instcount}}{%
    \ifciteseen
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {\iffirstonpage% NEW
           {\usebibmacro{cite:name}% NEW
            \usebibmacro{cite:title}}% NEW
           {\ifciteibid
              {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
              {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
                 {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
                 {\usebibmacro{cite:name}}%
               \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
%       \usebibmacro{cite:save}}% DELETED
        \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}% NEW
         {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:full}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\textheight=100pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite[99]{A01}.

Some text \autocite[99]{A01}.

\clearpage
\citereset

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\clearpage

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sorry I missed such an obvious one as the `ibidpage` option. To explicit the 2nd solution, one must remember to set `pagetracker=true` (it was already set to that in my example, I just want to specify it here for future reference).
There'd be some follow up questions I'd like to ask, should I post a new question or can we continue here?

Comment: @ChristophB. A new question would be better -- in fact, the present question would have been better as two or three separate questions.

Comment: okay, thank you very much for your help so far.