# Always print full author name biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm currently writing my thesis, and I've a problem, because when I print a cite more one time via `\footcite` command, the author first name is hidden.

But I must print every time the full name of the author.

I've read this post [About biblatex repeated citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58009/biblatex-tricks-with-repeated-citations-in-footnotes) but I can't solve my problem.

I call `biblatex` package with these options

```
\RequirePackage[%
style=verbose-trad2,
backend=biber,
dashed=false,
hyperref,
firstinits=false,
alldates=comp,
abbreviate=false,
idemtracker=false,
opcittracker=false,
language=french%
]{biblatex}
```

### mwe.tex

```
\documentclass{ownclass}%scrbook base (KOMA)
% Don't forget to parse with biber backend
\title{MWE}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\begin{document}
some text\footcite["quote"][2]{Dupont:2012fk}
\clearpage
some other text on a new page with another reference\footcite[21]{Me:2012uq} and another extract from the previous cite\footcite["quote"][2]{Dupont:2012fk}
My problem: firstnames (Tim \& Jean) aren't printed
\end{document}
```

### ownclass.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{ownclass}[15/11/2012 v1.0]
\LoadClass[12pt, oneside, a4paper]{book}
\RequirePackage[latin1,applemac,utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}

%Biber backend
\RequirePackage[%
style=verbose-trad2,
backend=biber,
dashed=false,
hyperref,
firstinits=false,
alldates=comp,
abbreviate=false,
idemtracker=false,
opcittracker=false,
language=french%
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} % ,

%Français
\RequirePackage[francais,frenchb]{babel}

\RequirePackage[babel]{csquotes} % Guillemets
\selectlanguage{french}
\frenchspacing
\FrenchFootnotes
```

### bib entries

```
@book{Me:2012uq,
    Author = {Me},
    Date-Added = {2012-11-05 23:58:33 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2012-11-05 23:59:00 +0000},
    Publisher = {SMB},
    Title = {Tex and Biblatex},
    Year = {2012}}

@book{Dupont:2012fk,
    Author = {Dupont, Jean and Burton, Tim},
    Date-Added = {2012-11-05 23:49:22 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2012-11-05 23:52:46 +0000},
    Publisher = {Publisher},
    Title = {Tintin},
    Year = {2012}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do. In your case: which document class do you use, which bibliography style ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to redefine the `cite:name` bib macro  with the option to print names with `first-last` option.

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:name}{%
  \printnames[first-last]{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\nametitledelim}}
```

Comment: Or just use `\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{first-last}`.