# biblatex autocite inbook has been referenced but does not exist

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

When clicking on the link in the footnote that should jump to the first appearances of a source, it is jumped to the first page of the document instead.

What I have so far:

.bib:

```
@inbook{HighfieldPosition_FourViews,
  author = {Highfield, R. },
  title = {God Controls by Liberating},
  pages = {141--164},
  year = 2011,
  crossref = "fourviewsdivineprovidence"
}


@inbook{CraigPosition_FourViews,
  author = {Craig, William Lane},
  title = {Response to Ron Highfield},
  pages = {165--175},
  year = 2011,
  crossref = "fourviewsdivineprovidence"
}

@book{fourviewsdivineprovidence,
  booktitle={Four Views on Divine Providence},
  author={Craig, W.L. and Highfield, R. and Boyd, G.A. and Helseth, P.K. and Jowers, D. and Gundry, S.N.}, 
  series={Counterpoints: Bible and Theology}, 
  year={2011},
  publisher={Zondervan}
}
```

in the text then:

```
blabla \autocite[143]{HighfieldPosition_FourViews}.
\end{quotation} blabla \autocite[175]{CraigPosition_FourViews}
```

The warning when compiling

> pdfTeX warning (dest): name{cite.0:fourviewsdivineprovidence} has been
>   referenc ed but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

Output looks good but wrong link. The blue "cit" jumps to page "i" :
[image]

What can I do to get the right page in the blue link?

Edit:

Here a complete example

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{article} 



\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}%
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-verbose]{biblatex}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58040/25029
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \bibhypertarget{cite\the\value{instcount}}{%
    \ifciteseen
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {\iffirstonpage% NEW
           {\usebibmacro{cite:name}% NEW
            \usebibmacro{cite:title}}% NEW
           {\ifciteibid
              {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
              {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
                 {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
                 {\usebibmacro{cite:name}}%
               \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
%       \usebibmacro{cite:save}}% DELETED
        \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}% NEW
         {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:full}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}}



\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}% Syntax for version >= 1.2  


% LAST PACKAGE == HYPERREF
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16269/25029
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}  % Colours hyperlinks in blue, but this can be distracting if there are many links.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


\newpage
asdasd
\newpage
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\autocite[143]{HighfieldPosition_FourViews}
\newpage
asdasd
yyyyyyyyyyy\autocite[175]{CraigPosition_FourViews}zzzzzzz
\newpage

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\label{Bibliography} 

\printbibliography[]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The redefinition from the answer in the link does seem to be quite specific to `verbose-trad2`. `verbose-trad2` does have quite a lot of hyperlink stuff definition in the `.cbx` file, so there might be quite a lot of work involved to make it work with `philosophy-verbose`.

Comment: so no solution for `philosophy-verbose` so far? no workaround either?

Comment: I do not think it will be easy, simply beacuse you want the citation to link to a different citation of a different source. Plus, the output as you have in your screenshot is not helpful at all since the reader has no way of knowing what the "cit." refers to. How is (s)he to know that the "cit." refers to the last work something was cited in?

Comment: It is not a different source. Both citations are inbook that share the same book. The citation of footnote 14 displays an article within a book but also lists the whole book (therefore the "in ..") and the citation in footnote 15 only has to state "cit" meaning that the whole book can be found before

Comment: Quite so but where is "before"? in note 14 or 13, or 12? So implicitly the reader already has to know where what the whole book is.

Comment: Hmm you are right. Well "before" means footnote 14 but I see that noone can know that.. Shouldn't biblatex take care of it? Maybe I should add the book twice with two different keys and every inbook gets its own book?

Comment: Giving each `inbook` its own `book` even though the two `book`s are identical kind of defeats the purpose of the `crossref` field, I would think. Since the problem technically persists without using the redefinition (`\renewbibmacro*{cite}`) you might want to contact the maintainer of `philosophy-verbose` directly.

Comment: thanks @moewe , I contacted the maintainer and if I don't get an answer, then I am going to use verbose-trad2 instead.

Comment: I have just checked and the problem seems solved. I don't get an error any more. Can we assume that a update in `biblatex-philosophy` solved your troubles?

Comment: The maintainer never replied and at this time I am not able to compile my project. Maybe my request has been taken seriously without notifying me, but I can not confirm. If it works for you now then fine.

Comment: That is interesting. Can you make sure to update to the newest versions, run this MWE later and update your post if there are any changes you get in output now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem cannot be reproduced with a recent version of `biblatex` and `biblatex-philosophy`.