# Ibid for citations with same title and page

Tags: biblatex

I use the style verbose-ibid, and I need it to use *ibid* (without a page number) when the last entry is exactly the same as the previous one (that is, same work, same page).

Right now, for the minimum working example below, the footnotes I get are

> Author. *Book A*, p. 1.
>   Ibid., p. 1.

However, I need

> Author. *Book A*, p. 1.
>   Ibid.

How do I do this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}

@book{a,
  title = {Book},
  author = {Author},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Here is some reference.\footcite[1]{a}
Here is some reference.\footcite[1]{a}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add the package option `ibidpage=true`. For details see my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58009/biblatex-tricks-with-repeated-citations-in-footnotes