# Force ibid in citation when using non-standard page numbers

Tags: biblatex

I am using BibLaTeX, and I need to cite a source by its headings, not by its page numbers. Is there any way to force BibLaTeX to use ibid when the title and location are the same?

Note: questions [Biblatex: tricks with repeated citations in footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58009/biblatex-tricks-with-repeated-citations-in-footnotes) and [Ibid for citations with same title and page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168971/ibid-for-citations-with-same-title-and-page) do not address this issue. I specifically need to cite using something other than the simple page number.

As far as I can see, I have used the correct package options (e.g., `ibidpage=true`). Here is the minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage
    [backend=biber,
     style=verbose-ibid,
     citepages=omit,
     ibidpage=true,
     firstinits=true]
   {biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{ibid.bib}

@book{a,
  title    = {Summa theologiae},
  author   = {{Thomas Aquinas}},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{ibid.bib}

\begin{document}

Here is some reference.\footcite[2]{a}
Here is some reference.\footcite[2]{a}
Here is some reference.\footcite[I, q.~1, a.~4]{a}
Here is some reference.\footcite[I, q.~1, a.~4]{a}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The footnotes I get for the first two, which use a standard page number are

> <sup>1</sup> Thomas Aquinas. *Summa theologiae*, p. 2.
>   <sup>2</sup> Ibid.

as expected. However, the other two, which uses the headings, produces

> <sup>3</sup> Ibid., I, q. 1, a. 4.
>   <sup>4</sup> Ibid., I, q. 1, a. 4.

The desired output for the fourth footnote is simply

> <sup>4</sup> Ibid.

Can this be done?

Comment: Try `loccittracker=context`. The `ibidpage` option implicitly sets `loccittracker=constrict`. See [pp. 55 sq. of the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), the `constrict` explanation states "In addition to that, this mode also checks if the `postnote` argument is numerical [...]."

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly. If you would like to receive a check mark, submit an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ibidpage` option in `verbose-ibid` sets `loccittracker=constrict` implicitly (see `verbose-ibid.cbx`). `loccittracker=strict` will not only distinguish footnote and body citations and suppress potentially ambiguous situations, it will also "check[...] if the `postnote` argument is numerical (based on `\ifnumerals` [...])." (pp. 60 sq. of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

That means that

```
Here is some reference.\footcite[2]{cicero}
Here is some reference.\footcite[2]{cicero}
```

is recognised as the same postnote because it is the same postnote in both cases and the postnote is numeric. But

```
Here is some reference.\footcite[I, q.~1, a.~4]{cicero}
Here is some reference.\footcite[I, q.~1, a.~4]{cicero}
```

does not pass the test even though the two postnotes are identical because they are not numeric as tested by `\ifnumerals`.

We can override this behaviour explicitly with `loccittracker=context`. With that option `biblatex` does not consider the outcome of the `\ifnumerals` test when checking for matching postnotes.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-ibid, citepages=omit,
  ibidpage=true, firstinits=true, loccittracker=context]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is some reference.\footcite[2]{cicero}
Here is some reference.\footcite[2]{cicero}
Here is some reference.\footcite[I, q.~1, a.~4]{cicero}
Here is some reference.\footcite[I, q.~1, a.~4]{cicero}
\end{document}
```

[image]